# Scroll a row into view programmatically in buffered grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6-classic

I have a buffered, grouped grid and I want to scroll into view a certain row (I have both the record and the record's/row's index at hand).

I have tried the undocumented

```
grid.getView().scrollRowIntoView(index)
```

but this only works in unbuffered grids, because it calls

```
view.getRow(row)
```

which only returns rows that are currently rendered, not the ones that are not rendered.

Is there an official function available I overlooked or what else can I do to scroll to the correct record?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

bufferedRenderer plugin has a function `scrollTo(recordIdx)`.

There is no function in `gridpanel` or `gridview` or `dataview` that calls `bufferedRenderer.scrollTo`, so I guess you have to call `getView().bufferedRenderer.scrollTo` directly from your grid.

Update: Please note that `scrollTo` may not be called if the store is empty, as this causes an error in the framework. Reason is that `scrollTo` takes the record index; if the index is below 0, it will be set to 0, if it is store.Count() or greater, it will be set to store.Count()-1 (which is -1 if the store is empty). Then, the record is fetched from the store (`getAt(index)`), which returns `null` if and only if the store is empty, and then it is checked that the record is indeed a model:

```
if(record.isModel)
```

which then causes the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isModel' of null

So you have to always check that the store is not empty before calling `scrollTo`:

```
if(view.store.getCount()) view.bufferedRenderer.scrollTo(index);
```

Answer (score 2):

The question has been crossposted in Sencha forum, [where Gary Schlosberg of the Sencha Support team](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?322530-Scroll-a-row-into-view-in-buffered-grid&s=993ec85aafebf2011a87b4404a83ad21&p=1152307#post1152307) answered:

> Have you tried the [`ensureVisible`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#method-ensureVisible) config? The callback option mentions usage with a BufferedStore.

Comment: It's not a config, it's a method call - but it works perfectly.  Just add code like this to a load event handler for your store:
`var selection = grid.getSelection();
if (selection && selection.length > 0)
    grid.ensureVisible(selection[0]);`
Then anytime the store loads you'll be sure the selcted record is visible.